# Algorithm for this power equation?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I have the following equation and want to determine $n$:

$$2^{2-n}+2\times 0.5^{2-n}-3=0$$

I happen to know that $n$ is a small integer and testing shows that $1$ and $2$ are both solutions.

But if I didn't have that (real world) information, would there be some exact solution to this equation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting $$t=2^{2-n}$$ then we get
$$t+\frac{2}{t}-3=0$$ and after multiplying by $t$ we get
$$t^2-3t+2=0$$

Answer (score 1):

with the substitution ${ 2 }^{ 2-n }=t$ $$2^{ 2-n }+2\cdot 0.5^{ 2-n }-3=0\\ 2^{ 2-n }+2\cdot 2^{ n-2 }-3=0\\ { 2 }^{ 2-n }=t\\ t+\frac { 2 }{ t } -3=0\\ { t }^{ 2 }-3t+2=0\\ \left( t-2 \right) \left( t-1 \right) =0\\ { t }_{ 1 }=2,{ t }_{ 2 }=1\\ { 2 }^{ 2-n }=2\Rightarrow n=1\\ { 2 }^{ 2-n }=1\Rightarrow n=2\\ $$

Comment: Thank you. But why does my solution $n=1$ not show up?

Comment: @G,it was a typo,because i had written $n-2$ istead of $2-n$

Comment: thanks for that.